Power Bi - Revenue per month for the duration of the order
I'm new to Power Bi and cannot find a solution for the following problem.
I' have a table with revenue data as follows:

Create Date (of Project)
Project Start
Status (offer, order)
Project End
date of closing
customer name
revenue per year
...

I want to display new revenues in a time period, for example for the years 2024 (Jan) until 2025 (Dec).
In a bar graph I want to show orders and offers. See the following link (first image on the side / red and blue) for an example of what I am looking for: https://www.instructorbrandon.com/power-bi-data-visualization-column-charts/
For example there are the following projects as orders

customer 1 - start 01/2024 end 12/2024 - 1000 € - show bar/revenue for 12 months

customer 2 - start 06/2024 end 12/2024 - 1000 € - show bar/revenue for 7 months

customer 3 - start 08/2024 end 07/2026 - 1000 € - show bar/revenue for 24 months

customer 4 - start 01/2024 end 12/2026 - 1000 € - show bar/revenue for 36 months


I want to cumulate the data overall for orders and on top there should another block of the bar.
I thank you in advance for any help with this problem.
I have tried to find a solution with chat gpt and several formulas with Dax and if conditions for the time period, but I couldn't find a solution.

total 1000 or 1000 for each month? pls also provide the expected output as well. You can draw charts in Excel for reference.

Hi Ryan,
thank you for your help in this case. I worked another 20 hours on the solution and finally found it. :-) Please see my answer to my question. :-)

For anyone who is interested, here is my solution:

Create a measure:

MonthlyRevenue =
CALCULATE(
SUMX(
Projects,
IF(
Projects[Status] = "Auftrag" &&
Projects[Start Date] <= MAX(DateTable[Date]) &&
(ISBLANK(Projects[End Date]) || Projects[End Date] >= MAX(DateTable[Date])),
Projects[Yearly Revenue] / 12,
0
)
)
)

Create another measure:

CumulativeRevenue =
CALCULATE(
[MonthlyRevenue],
FILTER(
ALL(DateTable),
DateTable[Date] <= MAX(DateTable[Date])
)
)

Create a Date table with a column for years and months:

Then use the year and the month of the date table on the x-axis and the CumulativeRevenue on the y-axis.
From the original list with projects this will generate a bar chart, where the revenue for each project and its monthly revenue is accumulated from the project start and until the project ends. Kind of Tetris with revenue blocks. ;-)
If you have offers and orders in your revenue list as a status of the project, you can use this status in the legend of the bar chart. So you will receive a bar chart with revenue curve for orders and on top potential revenue as offers.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
